# Boost asio async operation bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm usig boost asio for an IRC bot, and one of my async operation results in a bad file descriptor. I tried to put the socket in a shared_ptr, but I still got the "Bad File Descriptor" error. I don't know whats wrong in it.

Here are the files, I omitted some of the functions from the cpp file. But I you want to read the full file, it's [here](https://github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/irc-boost/blob/master/irc.cpp) on my Github.

The error happends in the _read function.

Thanks!

irc.hpp

```
#ifndef H_IRC
#define H_IRC

#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Irc 
{
    public:
        Irc(const std::string &server, const std::string &port, const std::function<void()> onConnect);

        void connect();
        void close();

        void user(const std::string &username);
        void user(const std::string &username, const std::string &hostname, const std::string &server, const std::string &realname);
        void nick(std::string &nickname);
        void join(const std::string &chan);
        void part(const std::string &chan);
        void privmsg(const std::string &to, const std::string &msg);
        void command(const std::string &cmd, const std::string &msg);
        void command(const std::string &cmd, const std::string &to, const std::string &msg);

        void run();

    private:
        void _read(const boost::system::error_code &error);
        void _send(std::string &message);
        void _readHandler(const boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > &tokenizer);
        void _connectHandler(const boost::system::error_code &error);

        void _pong(const std::string &ping);

        std::string _server;
        std::string _port;
        std::string _chan;
        std::vector<std::function<void (const boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> >&)>> _readHandlers;
        std::function<void()> _onConnect;
        boost::asio::streambuf _buffer;
        boost::asio::io_service _ios;
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _socket;
};

#endif
```

irc.cpp

```
#include "irc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

Irc::Irc(const std::string &server, const std::string &port, const std::function<void()> onConnect)
    : _server(server), _port(port), _onConnect(onConnect), 
      _socket(boost::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(boost::ref(_ios)))
{
    // Ping back handler
    _readHandlers.push_back([this](const boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > &tokenizer) {
        std::vector<std::string> tokens(begin(tokenizer), end(tokenizer)); 

        if(tokens[0].compare("PING") == 0)
            _pong(tokens[1]);   
    });

}

void Irc::connect()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(_server, _port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

    while(it != end)
    {
        if(!error)
            break;

        std::cout << "Connecting to " << _server << " " << _port << std::endl;

        boost::asio::async_connect(*_socket, it,
            boost::bind(&Irc::_connectHandler, this, error)
        );

        it++;

        if(error)
            std::cout << "Error : " << error.message() << std::endl;

    }

    if(error)
        std::cout << "Error connectinf to " << _server << " " << error.message() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Connection success" << std::endl;

}

void Irc::close()
{
    _socket->close();
    _ios.stop();
}

void Irc::run()
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(*_socket, _buffer, "\r\n",
        boost::bind(&Irc::_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );

    _ios.run();
}

/*
 * Private
 */

void Irc::_read(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error in read : " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string data(buffers_begin(_buffer.data()), buffers_begin(_buffer.data()) + _buffer.size());
        std::cout << data << std::endl;     

        boost::char_separator<char> sep("!@:; ");
        boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer(data, sep);

        _readHandler(tokenizer);
        boost::asio::async_read_until(*_socket, _buffer, "\r\n",
            boost::bind(&Irc::_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );

    }
}

inline void Irc::_send(std::string &message)
{
    boost::asio::write(*_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message + "\r\n"));
}

void Irc::_readHandler(const boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > &tokenizer)
{
    for(auto it : _readHandlers)
        it(tokenizer);
}

void Irc::_connectHandler(const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        _onConnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: looking at things http://livecoding.tv/sehe

Comment: @sehe : nice, I'll keep this on in my bookmarks, unfortunately I don't have flashplayer on my laptop.

Comment: Should already support HTML5 (lemme check). http://roadmap.livecoding.tv/ says week 4/2016

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xpk55U1.png maybe an option I didn't turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `connect` is never called.

> This causes the "bad file handle" error

### Further Notes

- Suddenly, `_send` uses *synchronous* `asio::write`. Why?
- Error handling should probably be added there, too (catch or pass `error_code&` argument).
- There's only one socket which never gets re-initialized or assigned. Embedding it into a shared pointer isn't changing anything¹.
- This however is strange:

  ```
      std::cout << "Connecting to " << _server << " " << _port << std::endl;

      boost::asio::async_connect(*_socket, it,
          boost::bind(&Irc::_connectHandler, this, error)
      );
  ```

  This does potentially many asynchronous connect operations **on the same socket** simultaneously. This is a data race and therefore [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), see: [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety).

  So you need to fix it to use several sockets or sequential.
  Turns out, this is very simple: you're already using the free function version of `async_connect`:

  - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect/overload1.html

  > This function attempts to connect a socket to one of a sequence of endpoints. ***It does this by repeated calls to the socket's `async_connect` member function, once for each endpoint in the sequence, until a connection is successfully established.***

  So the fix is to just call it once.
- Your bind doesn't use a placeholder, instead uses a hardcoded error!

  ```
  boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
  boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, it, boost::bind(&Irc::_connectHandler, this, error));
  ```

  Needs to be more like

  ```
  boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, it, boost::bind(&Irc::_connectHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error()));
  ```
- after handling incoming traffic, you need to consume the buffer contents, or it will infinitely repeat the same:

  ```
  _readHandler(tokenizer);

  _buffer.consume(_buffer.size());
  ```

### Pull Request

- https://github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/irc-boost/pull/1

Adds:

```
869c225 Use shared_ptr
9042c6d Add function level trace
50dee1b Revert shared_ptr and rename _onConnect(ed)
20475b9 Fixing the async_connect debacle
c6d8a2e Fixed channel handling and consistency join/part
6fd9242 Initiate `connect()` instead of read from `run()`
06a6c06 Do **not** assume contiguous buffer storage (UB)
090fe8c Consume handled input
68e5e8a Comment
```

All the above changed, I have successfully connected to an IRC channel and receiving mesages.

[image]

---

¹ (especially not unless you make sure something hangs on to an instance of the shared_ptr)

Comment: Finally, the result of my review in a PR: https://github.com/Bl4ckb0ne/irc-boost/pull/1 - You can see the recorded live stream of me coding those changes here: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/reviewing-a-toy-irc-bot-in-boost-asio/

Comment: Hi,
I just wanted to know how to run the program.. I was able to build the program by downloading the source from github as @sehe mentioned..  I need to know the steps.... The executable that is created runs fine...